Преобразовать SHELL cUrl в PHP
В API VK указано, что для загрузки требуется сформировать запрос на загрузку файла. В скрипте PHP путь к файлу (в той же папке) указан как $file = 'file_3.jpg';. URL для загрузки получаю корректно, POST-запрос формирую, но не пойму как мне загрузить данный файл указанным методом.
Пробовал следующий код, но он некорректный, в res я получаю NULL.
$myCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => upload_url(),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'photo' => new CURLFile('file_3.png')
    )
));
$response = curl_exec($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);



передать содержимое файла в multipart/form-data

ошибки курла то нельзя вывести что ли? зы: убедитесь, что файл действительно закгружается, лучше путь абслютный указывать
